# Does using a namespace in C# use more resources?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the amount of namespaces affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378972/do-the-amount-of-namespaces-affect-performance)

When you create a new class in C#, the default template includes several `using` lines at the top for LINQ and a couple others. Does having the namespaces included cause the application use more resources at run-time?

I rarely use anything in the LINQ namespace and I want to make sure I'm not paying the price for something I'm not using if I leave the lines there.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378972/do-the-amount-of-namespaces-affect-performance

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but on a related note: The excellent [PowerCommands for VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) extension adds a feature to Visual Studio that removes unused `using` directives when you save a source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not have *any* runtime performance. It's purely used during the compilation period (to find appropriate classes).

By the time C# code is compiled into IL, namespaces themselves don't exist anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you include will require more resources, however, this should only slow down your compile or link time not your program's actual run time.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not affect them, but if you right click and go to organize usings -> remove and sort it will then get rid of any using you are not using.